# Find if cookie name exists in the cookie string

Tags: javascript, strings, node.js, ecmascript-6, http

I need to determine whether a cookie name is available or not in the cookie string. I have achieved this. We could use the cookie-parser package but I don't want to use that package so I have written the below code. Can I reduce the code in a better way that is more optimised?

```js
    function checkCookie(cookie, cookieToBeSearched){
                if(cookie === "" || cookie === undefined){
                    return false
                }
                let res = cookie.split(";").some(cookie => {
                    let eachCookie = cookie.split("=");
                    return eachCookie[0].trim() === cookieToBeSearched
                });
                return res;
            }
    
    let cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.2091695351.1539084164; __qca=P0-338702612-1539084164095; __gads=ID=770d92bcdac8de40:T=1539084164:S=ALNI_MbsRKpoSJdn8tsdShMHMZUAR17uZA; _gid=GA1.2.798724103.1539582973";
    
    console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_gid"))
    
    console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_giddd"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Same functionality, smaller size

> Can I reduce the code in a better way more optimised?

If you want to optimize for size, then here's a suggestion for a more compact version:

```
function checkCookie(cookies, name) {
    return (cookies || '')
        .split(/;\s*/)
        .some(cookie => cookie.split('=', 1)[0] === name)
}
```

- `(cookies || '')` produces the same function result as the original `if(…) return false`
- `split` uses a regular expression that matches the space after the semicolon, saving the `trim` in the lines below
- the assignments for `eachCookie` and `res` can be removed, leading to a single line `some` call

**Benefits:** short & concise

**Limitations:** only checks for existence of a cookie, not its value

## Option 2: More versatility, similar size

There is an opportunity for a different design that allows for more generic use cases: you can first parse the cookie string into a plain object and then check for the existence of the cookie in question.

```
function parseCookie(cookie) {
    return (cookie || '')
        .split(/;\s*/)
        .reduce((result, entry) => {
            const [key, value] = entry.split('=', 2)
            result[key] = value
            return result
        }, {})
}

function checkCookie(cookies, name) {
    return Boolean(parseCookie(cookie)[name])
}
```

Granted, this a solution may be a bit "slower" than the original implementation. This shouldn't be an actual issue unless you intend to parse millions of cookie strings and time is a constraint.

What you gain in return though is a lean, readable, reusable function that lets you check for the existence of a cookie and in addition can also return the cookie’s value.

**Benefits:** check for cookie existence and get values; faster than original solution when checking multiple cookies

**Limitations:** no savings in size

## Option 3: Universal key-value parser, a bit larger

The above solution is based on code that I use to parse URL query strings. Both cookie- and query strings are key-value pairs, except cookies use a semicolon `;` as a separator, while query strings use an ampersand `&`. If we adapt our function to accept the separator and equals sign as (optional) parameters, we can parse query strings and cookies with the same function:

```
function parseValues(cookie, sep, eq) {
    sep = sep || /;\s*/
    eq = eq || '='

    return (cookie || '')
        .split(sep)
        .reduce((result, entry) => {
            const [key, value] = entry.split(eq, 2)
            result[key] = decodeURIComponent(value)
            return result
        }, {})
}

function parseCookies(cookies) {
    return parseValues(cookies)
}

function parseQuery(query) {
    return parseValues(query, '&')
}

function checkCookie(cookies, name) {
    return Boolean(parseCookie(cookie)[name])
}
```

### Option 4: Consider using libraries

I understand that you wanted to write your own function as opposed to introducing `cookie-parser`, which does a lot more than what you actually need - especially signing & signature verification - and is thus larger in size than what you aim for.

Other options would be `cookie` or `lightcookie`, which are smaller in size and might be a good choice over writing your own function.

```
const lightcookie = require('lightcookie')

function checkCookie(cookies, name) {
    return Boolean(lightcookie.parse(cookies)[name])
}
```

**Benefits:** save time; avoid mistakes; benfit from tested & verified code

**Limitations:** can be larger than what you are willing or able to include

Answer (score 0):

### Responding to your question

> *Can I reduce the code in a better way more optimised?*

There are multiple ways one could optimize the code. Other approaches are certainly possible. For example, you could merely use less functional approaches and instead use a more imperative approach. By replacing the `.some()` loop with a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, there will no longer be a function called for each element in the array, which will require less computational resources.

```js
function checkCookie(cookie, cookieToBeSearched) {
  if (cookie === "" || cookie === undefined) {
    return false
  }
  const pieces = cookie.split(";");
  for (piece of pieces) {
    const eachCookie = piece.split("=");
    if (eachCookie[0].trim() === cookieToBeSearched) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

let cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.2091695351.1539084164; __qca=P0-338702612-1539084164095; __gads=ID=770d92bcdac8de40:T=1539084164:S=ALNI_MbsRKpoSJdn8tsdShMHMZUAR17uZA; _gid=GA1.2.798724103.1539582973";

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_gid"))

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_ga"))

console.log("Cookie is available - ", checkCookie(cookie, "_giddd"))
```

Another option is instead of splitting the string on semi-colons and then calling `.some()`, one could use the regular expression method [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). The code below can be compared in [this jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/splitfind-vs-regexptest), which uses the same two tests as in your example, plus a third for testing the check for a cookie name at the beginning of a string. The test does not compare checking for a cookie name using an empty string - that might yield different results.

```js
function checkCookieRegExp(cookie, cookieToBeSearched) {
  if (cookie === "" || cookie === undefined) {
    return false
  }
  const pattern = new RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)' + cookieToBeSearched + '=');
  return pattern.test(cookie);
}
const cookie = "_ga=GA1.2.2091695351.1539084164; __qca=P0-338702612-1539084164095; __gads=ID=770d92bcdac8de40:T=1539084164:S=ALNI_MbsRKpoSJdn8tsdShMHMZUAR17uZA; _gid=GA1.2.798724103.1539582973";
const elementsToFind = [
    {name: '_gid', expectation: true},
    {name: '_ga', expectation: true},
    {name: '_giddd', expectation: false},
    {name: 'ID', expectation: false}
];
for (element of elementsToFind) {
    const result = checkCookieRegExp(cookie, element.name);
    const method = !(result == element.expectation)  && ('error' in console)?'error':'log';
    console[method](`result of finding "${element.name}":  ${result}`);
}
```

#### Other suggestions

Notice in both examples that [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) was used for any variable that wasn't re-declared. This avoids [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

Also, in your original code, the variable name `cookie` gets re-used in the arrow function. While this doesn't overwrite the original value because it has different scope, it is best to use a different name to allow use of the original value inside the arrow function and avoid confusion - not only for future yourself but anybody else reading your code.

[image: cookie name conflict]

Comment: Thanks for providing your answers, @sᴀᴍ-onᴇᴌᴀ!

The Regular Expression needs a small fix as it currently can return false positives, e.g. for `checkCookie(cookie, "ID")`.

The pattern `(?:^|;\s*)` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I tried the pattern you suggested but it didn't work for finding cookie name `_ga` in the example string

Comment: That’s interesting, @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ - I verified the pattern before commenting, would you mind trying it out here: https://regex101.com/r/bbPiKm/1 ?

Comment: Sorry I meant `_gid` wasn't getting found when it should - I wasn't escaping the `\s` properly